# how to add a equation to footnote?

Tags: footnotes

I want to add a equation to the footnote, but it does not work, as follow. Could you help me? Thank you!

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
this is \footnote{\begin{equation} $x=2$ \end{equation}}
\end{document}
```

Comment: You have excess `$` signs, try `\documentclass{article} 
\begin{document} 
this is \footnote{\begin{equation} x=2 \end{equation}} 
\end{document}`. That is, `\begin{equation} $x=2$ \end{equation}` throws an error regardless of whether you are in a footnote.

Comment: I assume that the equation in question is much larger than x=2, otherwise you are just wasting space.

Answer (score 1):

You have excess $ signs. That is,

```
\begin{equation} $x=2$ \end{equation}
```

throws an error regardless of whether or not you are in a footnote. Try

```
\documentclass{article} 
\begin{document} 
this is \footnote{\begin{equation} x=2 \end{equation}} 
\end{document}
```